# Photoshop alternative with same keyboard shorcuts

Tags: software-recommendation, shortcut-keys, photoshop

tldr; Is there a program with the same keyboard shortcuts and/or user interface as PS.

I know the "photoshop alternative" question has been asked so many times, but I feel this variant is worth the time to ask.

I am a web designer and have been using PS daily on a windows or mac machine for about 10 years, but I do most of my development in linux. The only thing that has been keeping me from the full switch to linux is PS. I have tried many alternatives, including GIMP, but I feel the barrier to entry is too high for one reason and one reason only, the keyboard shortcuts. Over the years I have become very adept and quick in the use of PS because of keyboard shortcuts and muscle memory. I realize that many shortcuts can be customized, but many actions are just too different from PS. So my question is what programs are out there that are the closest to PS in keyboard shortcuts and interface. I don't care if I have to do a bunch of customization to get it as close as possible, but I just can't take too much time to learn a completely new workflow. Of course I realize that any software will take time and effort, I just want to make that time/effort as minimal as possible.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

*edit* I should tell you the most important features and workflow I use on a daily basis are, Smart objects, linked documents, save for web and devises.

Comment: For web design, there's really no tool suited better than [Sketch](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/) in my opinion. It's built for that purpose and its power comes from its simplicity. We have only recently started using it at work and it is brilliant. The bad news is it's only in the **Mac App Store** (and it looks like you _really want_ a linux development environment). Have you considered a mac development environment?

Comment: yes. I have mac dev enviroment, but I have found that linux is much easier to use and setup. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try [GIMPshop](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimpshop.mirror/),

(**<s>http://www.gimpshop.com/</s> fake website**, Thanks @Glutanimate)

> GIMPshop is essentially Gimp with some cosmetic changes. The Gimp’s menu structure and naming conventions are a constant source of frustration for users accustomed to Photoshop.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMPshop

> An upstream source site housing the original files for this mirror is no longer available.
>
> GIMPshop is a modification of the free/open source GNU Image Manipulation Program (GIMP), intended to replicate the feel of Adobe Photoshop. Its primary purpose is to make users of Photoshop feel comfortable using GIMP. It shares all GIMP's advantages, including the long feature list and customisability, while addressing some common criticisms regarding the program's interface: GIMPshop modifies the menu structure to closely match Photoshop's, adjusts the program's terminology to match Adobe's, and, in the Windows version, uses a plugin called 'Deweirdifier' to combine the application's numerous windows in a similar manner to the MDI system used by most Windows graphics packages. While GIMPshop does not support Photoshop plugins, all GIMP's own plugins, filters, brushes, etc. remain available

Source: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimpshop.mirror/

Comment: Please note that the original Gimpshop creator is not affiliated with gimpshop.com. [In fact, the source and installers available on that website appear to contain adware and spyware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMPshop#Status).

Comment: A less drastic solution to getting a more PS-like layout with GIMP is provided in [this webupd8 tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/gimp-get-photoshop-like-keyboard.html).

Comment: GIMP is extremely unintuitive. Seems like the people behind it built the software for themselves and not ordinary users.

Answer (score 4):

If the nice folk at Microsoft are any guide, you will be in trouble down the line anyway.  When they moved from Office 2010 to Office 2013, all the keyboard shortcuts that I had spent years training my fingers to type changed.  The nice folk who wrote Gimp also have a [guide to the current keyboard shortcuts](http://www.gimpusers.com/gimp/hotkeys) and it possible within Gimp to map the function that you want to a set of keys - you could create the mapping that you want that way.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The issue I have with gimp is that it is missing my most used features in PS such as, smart object for non destructive editing and linked documents for making a single change that updates many documents.

Comment: Ah - that might be much harder to come by.

Comment: Perhaps there is a web app that meets my requirement? I know there are some popping up all the time.

Comment: Perhaps - I'm not much of a web development person myself, and it sounds as though you are accustomed to some very specific functions that make your job easier.